# Uiautomatorviewer Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist

Tags: adb, android-uiautomator

i can launch Uiautomatorviewer sucessfully, inspect any page/app at personal profile.

Once phone at work profile/launching any app installed under work profile then Uiautomatorviewer throws error:

```
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
```

i am not sure why it behave like this suddenly, it used to work regardless personal / work profile last week.
i don't remember i change any configuration...

please help to give me clues why? i have followed many previous post suggestion to restart adb server, kill appium server, restart phone/laptop, disable enable developer options...etc. none works....

I tried to inspect personal profile now, the same error occurred:

```
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!
```

updated: i used appium studio inspector and it works. I still not sure what happened to adb or uiautomator via command line? how do i debug it?

Comment: Maybe the issue is in the data that you're receiving from the server, and some data is missing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

found an answer

[com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Is a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193879/com-android-ddmlib-syncexception-is-a-directory)

```
try doing adb shell rm -rf /data/local/tmp and rebooting the phone first. it's ok if you get rm: /data/local/tmp: Permission denied. ignore it - it's for the tmp folder itself after its content was already removed (that's what you need anyway)
```